# error import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH

Tags: groovy, spring-security, grails-2.5

I update the grails from 2.3.11 to 2.5.6 with JDK 1.8.0_281.

It gives the following error:
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH

```
/plugins/spring-security-ui/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugins/springsecurity/ui/RegisterController.groovy: 19: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
 @ line 19, column 1.
   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH
   ^
```

I update the plugin to :

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC5"
compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC3"
```

it shows the warning:

No plugin [spring-security-ui-1.0-RC3] installed, cannot uninstall

and the error above, I am confused when am I making the mistake, any help appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH

You are using a plugin version that is not supported with Grails 2.5.6.  We removed `ApplicationHolder` in 2014.  The class does not exist in Grails 2.5.6.

Comment: Hi @Jeff, thank you for quick response, what should I use instead of import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH  ?? the error show in the class class RegisterController extends AbstractS2UiController {}

Comment: "what should I use instead of import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH" - What is it that you would like to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to update the existing project to grails 2.5.6 which supported officially with JDK 1.8.  when I try to run the project it gives this error: rg.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH  so what I do is from build config i increased the version to compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC3" and still shows that error: import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH
   ^. that is the main issue.